# Cookies in AJAX call from subdomain to domain above not sent

Tags: ajax, cookies

I have two domains:

```
test.local
editor.test.local
```

User signed up on domain `test.local` and browser get cookie with domain `.test.local` Now I want to use this cookie in AJAX call from `editor.test.local` to `test.local`, but **no cookies are send**. Is there any easy workaround to send cookies from subdomain, or should i use iframes and postmessages? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies can be shared across subdomains depending on how they are "scoped."

To scope a cookie to use across `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com` you set it to `.example.com` (with just the dot in front of the domain).

Aside from this mechanism, cookies are not supposed to "leak" across domains, which are defined by the tuple of a page's `domain, protocol and port`.

Comment: Thanks for response, althought I am not happy :)